# How to find frequency of every element row wise in a 2D matrix?

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

I am having a 2D-List as temp=[[0.5, 0.5, 2.0], [0.5, 0.5, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0], [0.5, 0.5, 2.0, -0.25], [-1.0, 2.0, -1.0, -1.0], [2.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0], [-1.0, -0.25, -1.0, -1.0]]
I want to get maximum frequency of an element in a row. For example taking index 1 for this list. We have frequency of '-1.0' as 3 and it is maximum in this list.
I am doing something like this. But getting 0 as output. Can someone help.

```
temp=[[0.5, 0.5, 2.0], [0.5, 0.5, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0], [0.5, 0.5, 2.0, -0.25], [-1.0, 2.0, -1.0, -1.0], [2.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0], [-1.0, -0.25, -1.0, -1.0]]
ct=0
maxi=0
for i in range(len(temp)):
    for j in range(len(temp[i])):
        ct=temp.count(temp[i][j])
        maxi=max(ct,maxi)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a mistake in your code.

I fixed it below.

```
temp=[[0.5, 0.5, 2.0], [0.5, 0.5, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0], [0.5, 0.5, 2.0, -0.25], [-1.0, 2.0, -1.0, -1.0], [2.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0], [-1.0, -0.25, -1.0, -1.0]]
ct=0
maxi=0
for i in range(len(temp)):
    for j in range(len(temp[i])):
        ct=temp[i].count(temp[i][j])
        maxi=max(ct,maxi)

print(maxi)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a python built-in library `Counter` with the method `most_common()` when looping over your list of lists `temp`. As following:

```
# sample data
temp=[[0.5, 0.5, 2.0], [0.5, 0.5, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0], [0.5, 0.5, 2.0, -0.25], [-1.0, 2.0, -1.0, -1.0], [2.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0], [-1.0, -0.25, -1.0, -1.0]]

from collections import Counter
for lst in temp:
    # return the top most common value and its frequency
    r = dict(Counter(lst).most_common(1))
    print(r)
```

Output:

```
{0.5: 2}
{-1.0: 3}
{0.5: 2}
{-1.0: 3}
{-1.0: 3}
{-1.0: 3}
```